# Loop return always the same last value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

im create a loop to create objects.

**Action.ts**

```
public campaing:any = {
    'id': '',
    'campaing_code': '',
    'campaing_type': '',
    'start_date': this.currentDate,
    'end_date': this.currentDate,
    'deadline': this.currentDate,
    'creation_date': this.currentDate,
    'special': false,
    'os': '',
    'country': '',
    'campaing_country': 'germany',
    'version_app': '',
    'permanent_promo': false,
    'promo_tag': 'ABS-W-',
    'editor_name': '',
    'plus_promotag': '',
    'status': 'Successful',
    'application': {},
    'publisher': {},
    'contact': '',
    'sended': false
  };
  public searchparram: any = {
    'type': '',
    'time': '',
    'start_date': this.currentDate,
    'deadline': this.currentDate,
    'publisher': {},
    'wildcard': false,
    'os': '',
    'category': '',
    'number_campaings': 1
  }
public suggescampaings:any = [];      
public generateCampaings(){
        this.campaing.campaing_code = this.searchparram.type;
        this.campaing.start_date = this.searchparram.start_date;
        this.campaing.deadline = this.searchparram.deadline;
        this.campaing.publisher = this.searchparram.publisher;
        this.campaing.os = this.searchparram.os;
        for (let i = 1; i <= this.searchparram.number_campaings; i++) {
          ((i)=>{
            this.campaing.id = i; /* Here should print i but alway print the last value of i */
            this.suggescampaings.push(this.campaing);
          })(i);
        }
      }
```

But when i try to put the camaping.id = i, always return the last value of the iteration. i mean if the iteraion is 8 times always give as id 8.

So the idea is to put as id the iteration and then push in to the array the object.

Comment: Because you're changing the same object (`this`)

Comment: Of course it will only have the last value. You are overwriting `this.campaing.id` on each loop. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are modifying the same `this.campaing` object in each loop. If you intended to push a new object for each loop, you can easily create a copy by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
for (let i = 1; i <= this.searchparram.number_campaings; i++) {
  ((i) => {
    let copy = Object.assign({}, this.campaing);
    copy.id = i;
    this.suggescampaings.push(copy);
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with the loop, It is because you have not created new object before pushing the object into an array `suggescampaings`. The same object `campaing` is getting overwritten multiple times, and if you display the array it is going to display the same object (i.e last object) multiple times.

**Suggestion** : Create new temporary object every time inside the loop then push it into an array.

Comment: I tried to create a new temporary object inside of the loop using but still happen the same. 
`let newcampaing:any = {}`

but sitll happen the same.

Comment: You should clone the object campaing to create temporary campaing object. So that reference is not the same.